# Xpath command - Returning contents of eg 2nd instance of a class which is in the 3rd instance of another class?

Tags: python, xpath

Could someone give me a first draft of the following search i need to perform using relative Xpath?

Get the contents/text of the 2nd instance of the class "FRED" which is in the 3rd instance of the CLASS "PETER"

Source looks something like;

```
<class peter> not me </class>
<class peter> not me </class>
<class peter> not me
    <class fred> not me </class>
    <class fred> this is what i need to get </class>
    <class fred> not me </class>
    <class fred> not me </class>
</class>
<class peter> not me </class>
<class peter> not me </class>
<class peter> not me </class>
<class peter> not me </class>
```

I want to reference the positions for peter and fred instances

I think I need something like;

//class[@peter][3]/class[@fred][2]

Comment: "Looks something like" isn't good enough. This isn't XML. If you show us the actual XML, then we can show you the actual XPath. Your attempt is close; but you need to give the attribute a name.

Comment: The actual XML is very complex and I would have to paste several hundred lines of code. I can't realistically expect anyone to wade through it. This is why I asked for a `first draft` to point me in the right direction with the syntax. I cannot find anything via google to target the code they way i need.

Comment: Your XPath expression looks fine to me. The closure tag of the 3rd instance of the class "peter" was wrongly placed though. If that was not an error, then you should use : `//class[@peter][3]/following::class[@fred][2]`

Comment: Your first draft is fine. To produce a second draft, we need to see some real XML. `<class peter>` is not real XML.